# CoreGraphics or Quartz Drawing keeps clearing

Tags: iphone, ios5, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I'm using

Where penLayer is a UIView

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(penLayer.frame.size);

CGContextRef  context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    //My Drawing Code
penLayer.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
[penLayer setNeedsDisplay];
```

This draws great but each time I call drawRect it wipes out what was before
Currently I'm having to save all drawing data to a dictionary

Is there anyway to prevent it from clearing out with each call to drawRect  and perhaps have a UIButton that calls clear  when needed ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a [BOOL property on UIView called `clearsContextBeforeDrawing`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/clearsContextBeforeDrawing). I'm assuming that you haven't used it. From the discussion in the documentation:

> When set to `YES`, the drawing buffer is automatically cleared to transparent black before the `drawRect:` method is called. This behavior ensures that there are no visual artifacts left over when the view’s contents are redrawn. If the view’s `opaque` property is also set to `YES`, the `backgroundColor` property of the view must not be nil or drawing errors may occur. The default value of this property is `YES`.
>
> If you set the value of this property to `NO`, you are responsible for ensuring the contents of the view are drawn properly in your `drawRect:` method. If your drawing code is already heavily optimized, setting this property is NO can improve performance, especially during scrolling when only a portion of the view might need to be redrawn.

Comment: thanks that does not appear to be it  In the storyboard it is unchecked   and in the awakeFromNib  it is set to NO

Comment: I don't think mine is clearing based on  drawRect  but perhaps based on the   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(penLayer.frame.size) call

Comment: Why did you accept the answer if it didn't solve your problem?